# Can't connect to server through SSH after rtcwake reboot

Tags: 14.04, server, ssh, cron, rtc

I used crontab to create an rtcwake command to shut my computer down at midnight, and start it up at noon. The problem is, once it turns off, and then on again, I can't connect to the server through Putty (an SSH client). The server computer is at a different building, so I can't check if it turns off, but it is definitely on after noon.

I added `1 0 * * * sudo rtcwake -u -m disk -s 43200` into crontab using `sudo crontab -e`